# in chrome: prevent iframe with input.focus from scrolling the main window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

this happens **only in chrome**:

take any webpage, add an `<iframe>` at the bottom, below the boundaries of the window so you'll have a scroll bar.

in the iframe have an `<input>` add a `focus()` event to the input.
e.g:

```
<script>
setTimeout(
    function(){
        $("#input").focus();
    },
    5000
);
</script>
```

the parent window (even from a different domain) scrolls to the iframe.

is there a way to prevent that?

[jsfidle for iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/6pxw4L2k/1/)

[jsfidle for parent window](http://jsfiddle.net/os3s9cyu/2/)

[-demo-](http://fiddle.jshell.net/os3s9cyu/2/show/)

Comment: I tested your fiddle and the above mentioned behavior was observed not only in chrome but all browser. It is an expected behavior irrespective of whether in an Iframe or not.